# CLRS pseudocode involving both subscripting and property access of a data structure

Tags: programming-languages, pseudocode

In Introduction to Algorithms, the stack data structure's enqueue operation has the following pseudocode

```
ENQUEUE(Q,x)
Q[Q.tail] = x
if Q.tail == Q.length
    Q.tail = 1
else Q.tail = Q.tail + 1
```

I started writing it in Swift and figured the queue should be modeled as a structure

```
struct IntQueue {
    var items = [Int]()
    var head = 0
    var tail = 0
}

func enqueue(queue: IntQueue, item: Int) {

}
```

to be able to access the `head` and `tail` properties. However, I'm not sure why the pseudocode subscripts `Q` directly. Is this shorthand for subscripting a queue's nested array property rather than the queue type itself?

Comment: You may have not realized that the answer to your question is in your question. That is, **pseudocode**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudocode we can use whatever convention we want, as long as the reader understands what we mean.

That said, in languages like python and C++ you can actually define the subscript operator to access the underlying array, and for such languages the pseudocode could work literally.